# 404 error on CreateView form_valid with more than 1 arguement

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

My proof App's `CreateView` takes 2 arguments "user" and "post". The user requirement is fulfilled by `self.object.user = self.request.user` How do I satisfy the `self.object.post` requirement. I am new to Django. I apologize if I am violating any Django rules

models.py

```
User = get_user_model() 
class Proof(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='proofmade')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='proofmade')
    made_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image_of_task= models.ImageField()
    proof_you_made_it = models.ImageField()
    suggestions = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

def __str__(self):
    return self.post.title
```

views.py

```
User = get_user_model()
class ProofCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   model = Proof
   fields = ('image_of_task', 'proof_you_made_it', 'suggestions')

   def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        ###### I think the following line may be wrong ##########
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')     
        print(slug)
        self.object.post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'proof'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new_proof/$', views.ProofCreate.as_view(), name='new_proof'),
```

Comment: Please show the URL pattern.

Comment: @Alasdair I have added URL pattern as requested. It creates a form lets me attach images and when I click submit it gives a 404 error

Comment: @Alasdair do you think I am making a mistake with slug = self.kwargs.get('slug') I have been trying all different options in the shell trying to figure how to associate the post to the proof

Comment: Where do you expect to get the slug from? There is no slug in the regex `r'^new_proof/$`.

Comment: @Alasdair I tried 2 different url patterns (see above). Any idea how I can call the post slug in the url. "post.slug" won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access `slug` from `self.kwargs` in the view, then you need `slug` in the URL. For example:

```
url(r'^new_proof/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProofCreate.as_view(), name='new_proof')
```

You don't need `username` because you are getting the user from `self.request.user`. In your second attempt, `post.slug` is incorrect because variable names can't contain dots.

In the view, I would use `slug = self.kwargs['slug']` unless you want it to be optional. At the moment `get()` returns `None`, so you get the error later on in your code.

Comment: I did try that too.

 NoReverseMatch at /posts/admin/tieing-a-knot/
Reverse for 'new_proof' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['proof/new_proof/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$']
Request Method: GET

Comment: Do you think it could be because when you say slug it is looking for proof slug. but in the proof models you can see that proof has no attribute slug. The post has a slug. Also post & user are a foreign key of Proof

Comment: with url(r'^new_proof/$', views.ProofCreate.as_view(), name='new_proof'), (old URL) the form shows up it lets me add images then when I hit submit. I get errors Do you think change something in the form_valid maybe slug = self.kwargs.get('slug'). If I add slug in the url the form does not show up

Comment: No, I've already explained why you shouldn't use `self.kwargs.get('slug').` The `NoReverseMatch at /posts/admin/tieing-a-knot/` error is a different issue, which is occurring on a different view/template.

Comment: Can you advise what I can use instead of self.kwargs.get('slug'). I can't figure it out. I have been trying to play with "related_name to somehow make it work

Comment: I actually have the models & views of posts as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954840/django-createviews-with-2-arguements-user-and-post

Comment: I already said what you should use instead of `get()` - use `slug = self.kwargs['slug']`. You don’t need to change `related_name` - you need to fix the view/template that is giving the `NoReverseMatch` error.

Comment: awesome dude you are the best. You cracked it " :)" this worked like magic

Comment: That's a different question, it doesn't belong in the comments.

Comment: sorry I have asked it as a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960589/deleteview-with-2-arguements-post-and-user

Comment: Hi Alasdair, do you think you can help me with another Django question, No one can figure the solution for the past 3 days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203999/removing-images-image-titles-image-description-from-a-post-with-multiple-image