# DeleteView with 2 arguements post and user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I have a delete view with **2** conditions "post" and "user".

The user requirement is fulfilled by `self.object.user = self.request.user` and post requirement is fulfilled by `slug = self.kwargs['slug']`(I think this may be the culprit)

Are my views correct?

I am new to **python** please forgive any silly mistakes.

Views.py

```
class ProofDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Proof

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        print(slug)
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.made.all():
                obj.made.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.made.add(user)
        return url_
```

models.py

```
User = get_user_model() 
class Proof(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='proofmade')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='proofmade')
    made_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image_of_proof= models.ImageField()
    proof_ = models.ImageField()
    suggestions = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

def __str__(self):
    return self.post.title
```

urls.py

```
    app_name = 'proof'

    urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^new_proof/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProofCreate.as_view(), name='new_proof'),

        url(r'^proof_delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProofDelete.as_view(),name='proof_delete'),
```

also tried

```
url (r'^proof_delete/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProofDelete.as_view(), name='proof_delete'),
```

I get the below error. Indicating error in the views

[Error Message Click to see Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSgo0.png)

[Same error message after scrolling down. Click to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7eH9.jpg)

Comment: You're not passing a `slug` parameter to the view, through the URL, so there's no `self.kwargs['slug']`.

Comment: I can try url

(r'^proof_delete/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProofDelete.as_view(),
        name='proof_delete'),


but I am not sure how to call that in the template

Comment: @PauloAlmeida I have updated the Url with the slug. but its not working. I guess I have to figure out how to call pk in the templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the templates. Adding a forloop after the "if" statement solved the issue. Doing this handles both arguments of the Url. "slug" of "post" model and "pk" of the "proof" model. Without the forloop It was almost impossible to satisfy both arguments of the URL

The correct Url thanks to "Paulo Almeida"

```
url (r'^proof_delete/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProofDelete.as_view(), name='proof_delete')
```

Below is the template

```
{% if user in post.made.all %}
    {% for proof in user.proofmade.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'proof:proof_delete' slug=post.slug pk=proof.pk %}">
            <img src="{% static 'images/thumbs_up_RED.png' %}" height="25px">
        </a><br/>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'proof:new_proof' slug=post.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'images/thumbs_up_BLANK.png' %}" height="25px">
    </a><br/>
{% endif %}
```